# Variable in the exponent?

Tags: linear-algebra

**This is straight from my homework, so please do NOT solve it for me!!**

This is the easiest of the kind from my homework, and is under the 'Logarithms' chapter.

$$10^{-4x} = 62$$

Round to the nearest hundredth.

I'm not sure how to start it, if it did not have the x in the exponent, I'd take the -4th root of both sides.

Because this is under Logorithms, I'd start with:

$10^{62} = -4x$

Is this the next step? ${log_{10}}^{62} = -4x$

Comment: What about: $ 10^{62} = -4x $?

Comment: @GeekyDewd No.  $10^2=100$.  Does $10^{100}=2$?

Comment: I can't edit my earlier comment,  meant this: ${log_{10}}^{62} = -4x$ If I am not mistaken I believe this is how my teacher did it on the bored.

Comment: For future reference, use {} for exponents longer than a single character.  Also works for fractions and square roots.

Comment: Thank you Mike, formatting is a battle for me, Lol!

Comment: Ah, yes, you can take the log of both sides.  You could even do what you suggested in your question and say $10^x=62^{-0.25}$, then  take the log of both sides.

Comment: Which is correct? ${log_{10}}^{62} = -4x$ OR ${log_{10}} (62) = -4x$. The first one I think the 62 is an exponent to the log of base 10, the second one is a log of (stuff) = something, right?

Comment: The second is correct.  It's not written as an exponent.  I've also learned to write it as $\log 62$, although apparently math majors use "log" for natural log (base $e$) rather than common log (base 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(-4x)\log_{10}10=\log_{10}62\\
\implies x=-\dfrac{\log_{10}62}{4}$$
Now, use a calculator.

Comment: I am not suggested to use a calculator because they are not allowed during the exam.

Comment: @GeekyDewd Maybe you have a logarithm table?

Comment: @GeekyDewd What are you allowed to use if you have to round it to the nearest hundredth?  Tables?

Comment: Oh, Yeah I can use a calculator once I am done, to get the approximation, I didn't think that was done.